# MySQL escaping special characters

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, character, sql-like

So, I have the following table:

```
ID  product
1   usb-stick
2   blackberry
3   cup of tea
4   usb-stick 2.0
5   computer
```

And wanted to achieve that whenever I look through my data with the LIKE condition, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product LIKE '% <value> %'
```

I would get the result I was searching for. But because there are special characters stored inside of my colums, I have to write down the actual value in order to have these back as a result.

So my question here is, if there is any way on how I could escape the special characters (which are stored inside of my colums, ex: usb-stick) in order to be searchable aswell for the following statement(s):

```
ID  product         title / keyword (seperated by comma) product must be searchable for
1   usb-stick       usb stick, usb        stick (notice the spaces)
2   blackberry      blackberry, black berry
3   cup of tea      cup of tee
4   usb-stick 2.0   usb stick 2.0, usb stick 2, usb-stick 2, etc
5   computer        computer
```

In short, I just want the product to be searchable for other statements aswell (so not only the actual value / title).

Help would be appericiated!

Comment: you can use `replace()` if you have always "," char

Comment: @FabioCardoso The characters, could be anything. For example the client searching statement equals to: usb - stick, which would be seen as product 1. Basically I just want the special characters sort out inside of the value, but the only reason it's there is for the correct information whenever the information is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()`

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE replace(product , '-', '') LIKE '% <value> %'
```

Edit, this is not friendly at all but could work:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(
                                            REPLACE(
                                                REPLACE(
                                                    REPLACE(
                                                        REPLACE(
                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                    REPLACE(
                                                                        REPLACE(
                                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                                    REPLACE(
                                                                                        REPLACE(
                                                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                                                    REPLACE(
                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                    REPLACE(
                                                                        REPLACE(
                                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                                    REPLACE(
                                                                                        REPLACE(product, '\"', ''),
                                                                                    '.', ''),
                                                                                '?', ''),
                                                                            '`', ''),
                                                                        '<', ''),
                                                                    '=', ''),
                                                                '{', ''),
                                                                                                    '}', ''),
                                                                                                '[', ''),
                                                                                            ']', ''),
                                                                                        '|', ''),
                                                                                    '\'', ''),
                                                                                ':', ''),
                                                                            ';', ''),
                                                                        '~', ''),
                                                                    '!', ''),
                                                                '@', ''),
                                                            '#', ''),
                                                        '$', ''),
                                                    '%', ''),
                                                '^', ''),
                                            '&', ''),
                                        '*', ''),
                                    '_', ''),
                                '+', ''),
                            ',', ''),
                        '/', ''),
                    '(', ''),
                ')', ''),
            '-', ''),
        '>', ''),
    ' ', '-'),
'--', '-') like '% <value> %'
```

Comment: Oh lord, I feel so stupid right now.. I actually thought that this would've update the column, but there is no possibility since you're selecting the row. Thank you so much.. How am I able to do this for multiple conditions by the way?

Comment: what multiple conditions do you want?

Comment: Actually, almost every special character, <,>./?:;"{}[]'!@#$%^&*()_-+=\|

Comment: I have a solution but is not friendly, I edited my answer.

Comment: I've seen it, it sure is not friendly. Is there an opportunity to validate / clear it with a regular expression or something similar?

Comment: Because it wouldn't match the value i'll be looking for. The search query will search for that specific value, but there is no value stored in the column for that. So that's why it has to be done from MySQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85509/discussion-between-bilal075-and-fabio-cardoso).